# Determine complex polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, maximum-principle

**Problem**

Let $P(z) = z^n + a_{n−1}z^{n−1} + \cdots + a_1z + a_0$ be a polynomial of degree $n > 0$. Show
that if $\lvert P(z) \lvert \le 1$ whenever $\lvert z \rvert = 1$ then $P(z) = z^n$.

---

I have tried to see $\dfrac{P(z)}{z^n}$, but nothing happens. I wonder which theorems should I use to solve this.

I think hints are enough.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** let $Q(z):=z^nP(z^{-1})$, which is a polynomial. Then $|Q(z)|\leqslant 1$ when $|z|=1$ and $Q(0)=1$ so by maximum modulus principle...

Comment: Short and straight to the point, +1.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Schwarz lemma and maximum prinicple

Comment: Schwarz Lemma says $P(z)\le 1$ for all the points $|z|\le 1$, this one says $|z|=1$.

Comment: @yimin for this i need the maximum priniciple :)

Comment: I got it, thanks. :D

Comment: Why and how do you use Schwarz lemma?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo schwarz lemma gives you $|f'(0)|\leq 1 $ and in general $|f^{n}(0)|\leq n! $

Comment: Do we need $f(0)=0$?

Comment: How you mean need? for schwarz lemma yes, and for the proof too as else $a_0$ wouldn't be $0$

Comment: I meant in order to use Schwarz lemma.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach.  By Rouché's theorem $z^n - \varepsilon\, P(z)$ has $n$ roots in the unit disc for all $\varepsilon \in (0, 1)$.  This implies that

$$0 \leq \frac{\varepsilon \,|a_k|}{1-\varepsilon} \leq {n \choose k}$$

for $k \in \{0, \dotsc, n-1\}$ or in other words

$$0 \leq |a_k| \leq \frac{1-\varepsilon}{\varepsilon}{n \choose k}.$$

Now let $\varepsilon \to 1$.